# Oracle ADF: How to populate DepartmentId value from managed backing or managed beans

Tags: java, jsf, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have a page called addPage.jsf in that I drag and dropped departmentsView1 data control as a form. Am using departments table of hr schema. After createInsert operation I will the the page with the empty fields of department table except departmentId. I need to populate department id from backing bean or managed bean. like below

[image]

I tried with the following. In backing bean of this page I have a field idVal of type int and setters and getters for this. field. In the property inspecter for departmentId , I have pasted #{backingBeanScope.backing_addPage.idVal}. But when I press commit record is not inseted to db and showing some error.

Error
Attribute DepartmentId in AppModule.DepartmentsView1 is required.

If am wrong any where please correct me.

My requirement is I have form created from view object and I need to populate id value from backing bean or managed bean so that user no need to enter the id value.

Comment: Is that *required field* message associated with the `DepartmentId` field? What is the scope of the corresponding bean? You will at least need a view scoped managed bean so as to maintain the instance of the bean on every post-back you make and If I were you, I would not be willing to explicitly show such auto-generated key values to end-users.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I made my bean's scope as session. But No use. Same Error. Actually my application is required to show id to user.

Comment: This message, `Error Attribute DepartmentId in AppModule.DepartmentsView1 is required` indicates the the field is not provided any value. The value may somehow be lost prior to submitting the form (I am not familiar with Oracle-ADF, if it has to do something with the concrete problem).

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way of doing this is to populate department id from DepartmentVORowImpl.create(AttributeList) method, as below:

```
 @Override
 protected void create(AttributeList attributeList) {

        super.create(attributeList);

        this.setDepartmentId(....);
 }
```

In case you use a db sequence (Oracle db) to generate department id value, you can use this code:

```
@Override
public void create(AttributeList attributeList) {
  super.create(attributeList);
  SequenceImpl seq = new SequenceImpl("LOG_SEQ", getDBTransaction());
  Number seqNextval = seq.getSequenceNumber();
  setDepartmentId(seqNextval);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On click Commit you are calling the operation binding directly or calling some method and then calling the operation binding there programatically..?

Also please let me know that how you are calling the createInsert ? its declaratively or programmatically..?